# Async non blocking threading in c#

Tags: c#, ssis

I want to execute SSIS package for many files from C# console application. I want that 4 instances of same package will run simultaneously on 4 different files. As soon as SSIS package execution COMPLETES for one of the file, it should allow another thread to enter and pick another file for execution. I tried with 'Parallel.ForEach', but it starts 4 threads at a time but does not wait for its completion so system gets hanged due to resource stuck. Async, await also gave me the same issue. Even I tried with SemaphoreSlim approach but no luck. Please help.

Parallel.ForEach:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    { Parallel.ForEach(Files, new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },(FileInfo filename) => CallChild(filename));
    }
     public static void CallChild(FileInfo fn)
    {
    }
```

Await and Async:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(4);
        try
        {
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                _semaphore.WaitAsync();
                CallChild(file);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
public static async Task CallChild(FileInfo fn){}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your tries? For Parallel.ForEach and Async.

Comment: Edited my Question with Code

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  You state that you want 4 instances to run simultaneously but then mention they need to wait, one after another, to execute.  Just don't run this asynchronously, and each operation will fire off one at a time.  We'll need a little bit more information than this.  Currently your request is a bit contradictory.

Comment: You use an asynchronous approach when you want to work on the same resource at the same time. But since you said you can only work on file after previous completes, you are better off using a synchronous approach because you will gain nothing from using threads or any other asynchronous stuff.

Comment: I mean, 4 instances of same ssis package will start which will pick 4 different files but after that , next thread will wait until one of these executes SSIS package completely. As soon as it finds that one thread has COMPLETED its SSIS execution, then only next thread will start with next file. Currently, 4 thread start their work simultaneously but after that next thread do not wait for one to complete due to which at some extent many instances of SSIS package start running that cause in hanging of system.

Comment: Apologies for not getting this but help me understand by asking a different question.  Why won't a standard foreach loop work, without any async handling?  In other words, what happens when you execute the `foreach` code without using the semaphore?

Comment: For Normal ForEach loop, it will execute in serial manner with 1 ssis package at a time. I want to improve the performance by executing it in parallel manner since I have high configuration on server to handle this parallelism.